# is there a Mysql adapter for DBT?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am looking for a mysql/mariadb adapter for dbt (https://www.getdbt.com/). I am guessing at least a partial one exists somewhere, but I have not been able to find it. Any leads?

Answer (score 2):

I just published an initial adapter for MySQL:

https://pypi.org/project/dbt-mysql/

Any bug reports are welcome!

I only tested against MySQL 8.0, and it probably won't work with MySQL 5.x due to lack of support for Common Table Expressions (CTE) / WITH clause.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anyone doing analytics directly on MySQL. 
People usually choose data warehouses for that instead of OLTPs. For example Redshift or BigQuery. If you have one of those setup, you can extract data out of MySQL as a source with for example singer/stitch or AWS Lake Formation, and do your analytics with dbt in your Data Warehouse.

That said, you can build a new adapter according to the docs: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-new-adapter

Comment: some services (Alibaba AnalyticDB, Data Lake Analytics) uses MySQL wire protocol. even MySQL 8 sometimes is enough